# Updating Qt Images does not work until exec is called

Tags: c++, qt

I need to create a simple GUI which displays images, the images in this example can change and the GUI will need to update it's contents.

I wrote the following update function in my widget class:

```
void myClass::updatePic() {
  QPixmap pix("./pic.png");
  int width = ui->picLabel->width();
  int height = ui->picLabel->height();
  ui->picLabel->setPixmap(pix.scaled(width,height,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));}
```

I try to use it in the following manner:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
QApplication a(argc, argv);
myClass w;
w.show();

sleep(3);
w.updatePic();

sleep(3);
w.updatePic();

sleep(3);
return a.exec();}
```

But the window just opens and does not display the images until we get to the `a.exec()` line, and then it opens the last image. What am I doing wrong?

---

EDIT:

Clarification, the trigger for changing the images comes from an external program (specifically, the gui will be a node in ros, and will be triggered by another node). Is there a way to push a button not from the gui via an external program? the timer will work but I dislike this "busy wait" style solutions.

Thanks for the suggestions so far

Answer (score 2):

`exec` runs the QT event loop, which includes rendering widgets.

So move your `updatePic` call into your widget and activate it by for example a button or in the show event

Comment: The trigger is from an external program, the QT GUI only displays the results and will have no buttons.

Answer (score 1):

At first learn more about event loop. In particular, you must know that all events like `paintEvent` or `resizeEvent` are usually called on corresponding events handle. The events handle is usually called by the event loop, i.e. inside of `exec` function.

Let's unite answers of @MohaBou and @RvdK. You need to handle timer shots after the `exec` call. Use `QObject::timerEvent` for this.

```
myClass::myClass()
{
    <...>

    // This two variables are members of myClass.
    _timerId = startTimer(3000);
    _updatesCount = 0;
}

myClass::~myClass()
{
    <...>

    // For any case. As far as I remember, otherwise the late event
    // may be handled after the destructor. Maybe it is false, do
    // not remember...
    if (_timerId >= 0) {
        killTimer(_timerId);
        _timerId = - 1;
    }
}

myClass::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if (event->timerId() == _timerId) {
        if (_updatesCount < 2) {
            updatePic();
            ++_updatesCount;
        } else {
            killTimer(_timerId);
            _timerId = - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The `startTimer` method here adds especial timer event to the event query every 3 seconds. As all events, it may be handled only when the event loop will take control and all earlier events are handled. Because of it you can have a duration if many "heavy" events are handled.

**EDIT:** sorry, I didn't understand @MohaBou at first read. His answer with explicit `QTimer` is also good enough (but I still don't understand a part about modality).

Answer (score 0):

The function exec also renders the child widgets. exec() blocks the application flow while show() doesn't. So, exec is mainly used for modal dialogs.

I recommend to update it in your custom witget by using a refresh timer. Use a QTimer  to update the image every 3 secs:

```
QTimer* timer = new QTimer(this);
timer->setInterval(3000);
connect(timer, SINGAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updatPicture()));
```

Update your picture in your custom slot:

```
MainWindow::updatePicture() {
    updatePic()
}
```

If you want, you could use a lambda function:

```
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this,  [&w]() {
    updatePic()
});
```

Comment: Here is a talk about `QApplication::exec` that is necessary in almost any GUI application. What did you mean about modal dialogs?